# Fatal error exception call to a member function on null

Tags: laravel-5

I created a function named yetkisi_var_mi in my User model as follows

```
public function yetkisi_var_mi ($ yetki)
{
    foreach ($ this-> roles () -> get () as $ role)
    {
        if ($ role-> name == $ yetki)
        {
            return true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

when I call this function in my blade file it gives a fatal error exception error.

```
<input type="checkbox"   class="durum" data-id="{{$talep->id}}" data-url="/talep/durum-degis" {{$talep->user->yetkisi_var_mi("author") ? "checked" : null}} >
```

Comment: What  $talep is equel to?

Comment: talep means request for authority